# Difference between if statement multiple condition and matching multiple values

Tags: c#, if-statement, multiple-conditions

I was working on something and found this problem.

let's say:

```
Result = KeyValuePair<bool,bool>;
```

I Used if statement to do some works according to Result Values..

1:

```
if (Result.Key == false && Result.Value == true)
{
  //Do Some Work
}
```

2:

```
if (Result.Key == Result.Value == false)
{
  //Do Other Work
}
```

But i found that it uses both if Result.Key=false !!

Why is that?

in Number 2 : Result.Value = true, So i think the condition doesn't apply in this case.
doesn't Number 2 Statement means or same as  (Result.Key = false && Result.Value==false)?!

why is it being used when Result.Value==true?

PS: I know i can just use (Else If), but i just wanna know what's going on..

Thanks.

Comment: Not sure what you mean. However in case 2, if `Result.Value` is `true` and `Result.Key` is `false` then the if block will be executed since the condition is the same as `Result.Key == (Result.Value == false)`. So if the second condition is `false` (i.e. `Result.Value` is `true`) then then whole condition is `true` if `Result.Key` is `false`. Makes sense?

Comment: yes:) it does make sense

Comment: If this makes sense, so pleas, accept one of the answers (both are the same). Thanks :)

Comment: Sure i will, i just want to understand it completely

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
if (Result.Key == Result.Value == false)
{
   //Do Other Work
}
```

this is the same as

```
if ((Result.Key == Result.Value) == false)
{
   //Do Other Work
}
```

which is the same as

```
if (Result.Key != Result.Value)
{
   //Do Other Work
}
```

Unless i got confused and `(Result.Key == Result.Value == false)` is actually the same as `(Result.Key == (Result.Value == false))`, which in this case still is `Result.Key != Result.Value`. It's confusing, so please never ever chain equality operators. It won't work the way you expect it to.

You can look up the rules in great detail here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/126fe14k.aspx

Answer (score 1):

This is related to the order of evaluation in the if condition.

Result.Key = false.
Result.Value = true

The first comparison, Result.Key == Result.Value will return false.
Then, the second evaluation will be false == false, that is true.

So, in this case, the block will be executed.

Comment: so, it goes through stages?! why is that? what if it's not bool,bool comparison? String,String for ex : A=Yes and B=No.. What would happen if we used if(A==B==Yes)? Will be used too?

Comment: @Dr.Vision The same again. (A==B=="Yes") is the same as ((A==B)=="Yes"). Which results in an invalid attempt to compare a boolean to a string (false == "Yes"), so it won't compile.